# Updating component after mediaDevice change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update my component after a new microphone is selected.
I believe I should add a resolved value of

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
        });
```

in useEffect?

At the moment, it looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import AudioAnalyser from '../containers/AudioAnalyser'



function DeviceSelectionBody(props) {
    const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        getMicrophone()
    }, [])


    const getMicrophone = async () => {
        const audio = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
        });
        setAudio(audio)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p> Select the audio and video devices from the list below:</p>
            <div >
                <label htmlFor="cameraList" className="control-label"><i className="fas fa-video" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Camera</label>
                <select className='form-control' id='cameraList' onChange={(e) => props.selectCamera(e.target.value)}>
                    {props.cameraOptions.map((item, index) => {
                        return <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.text}</option>
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label htmlFor="micList" className="control-label" ><i className="fas fa-microphone"></i>&nbsp;Microphone</label>
                <select className='form-control' id='micList' onChange={(e) => props.selectMic(e.target.value)}>
                    {props.micOptions.map((item, index) => {
                        return <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.text}</option>
                    })}
                </select>
                {audio !== null ? <AudioAnalyser audio={audio} /> : ''}
            </div>
            <div >
                <label htmlFor="speakerList" className="control-label"><i className="fas fa-volume"></i>&nbsp;Speaker</label>
                <select className='form-control' id='speakersList' onChange={(e) => props.selectSpeakers(e.target.value)}>
                    {props.speakersOptions.map((item, index) => {
                        return <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.text}</option>
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DeviceSelectionBody
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the microphone changing method is given by the parent (`props.selectMic`). I would then inject the id of the selected mic into the component you are working on and then call `getMicrophone(id)` inside the useEffect.

It would look something like this:

```js
  function DeviceSelectionBody(props) {
    const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null)

    const micId = props.selectedMicId; // the selected device id injected from the parent component
    useEffect(() => {
        getMicrophone(micId);
    }, [micId])


    const getMicrophone = async (deviceId = null) => {
        const constraints = deviceId ? { audio: {deviceId}} : {audio: true};
        const audio = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        setAudio(audio);
    }
```